# Как получить массив заголовков объектов JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Назовём файл JSON `template` и подключим его: `const template = require('./template.json');`

Дальше идёт его внутренний код:

```
"228": {
    "name": "Пример"
}
"1337": {
    "name": "Пример2"
}
```

Как из этого кода получить заголовки 228 и 1337 в массив: `var arr = ["228", "1337"]`
Чтобы после сделать вот так:

```
for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    console.log(template[arr[i]].name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let template = `{
  "228": {
    "name": "Пример"
  },
  "1337": {
    "name": "Пример2"
  }
}`;

//json сроку в js объект
template = JSON.parse(template);

//получаем ключи объекта в виде массива
const arr = Object.keys(template);

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(template[arr[i]].name);
}

//но ключи объекта можно перебрать и сразу, не получая их в виде массива
for (key in template) {
  console.log(template[key].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно отправить запрос на данный файл, я буду использовать axios для облегчённой работы с запросами.

```
axios.get("template.json").then(result => {
  console.log(result.data["228"].name);
  console.log(result.data["1337"].name);
});
```

Если реализовывать без axios, вам нужно отправлять запрос через `XMLHttpRequest()`.
Про него вы можете почитать в интернете, в оффициальной документации.
Вот так можно подключить axios: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Ну вообще у вас json какой-то странный. Пример того, что вы хотите:

```js
// Предположим, что jsonStr - это данные, которые вы вытягиваете из файла
let jsonStr = '{"data":[{"name":"Пример1"}, {"name":"Пример2"}, {"name":"Пример3"}]}';
let {data} = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

let arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    arr.push(data[i].name)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать цикл `for in`

```js
var obj = {
 "228": {
  "name": "Пример"
 },
 "1337": {
  "name": "Пример2"
 }
}
for (var n in obj) {
 console.log(obj[n].name);
}
```